# Is there value for including the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on the Login action?

Tags: security, asp.net-core-mvc, csrf

I am in the process of learning ASP.NET Core MVC and the book I am reading includes the following code example:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel) 
{
    // More stuff goes here.
}
```

You can see that the author includes the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on the action method. As far as my research goes, there does not appear to be any harm on including the attribute but I also not sure there is a benefit.

Based on my understanding on how the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] works, it looks like all that its achieving here is preventing a malicious website from logging me in... not sure I see the harm on someone trying to do that.

Clearly I am missing something , so my question is, what exactly is the use of the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] trying to prevent in this specific scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an internal application at a bank. As the victim, you have access and credentials for a strictly audited transactional application. Your colleague, the attacker doesn't have credentials, but manages to get to know your username and password somehow. Without login csrf, he can use your credentials to log on himself, but the source of the requests he makes (eg. the source IP) will be associated with him, and you can plausibly deny any action done by him. With login csrf, he might be able to get you to visit his malicious website (which can also be external, if you are visiting from an internal client), and he can use csrf to log you in, with your credentials, from your own pc, with no audit trace to him, and then exploit any other csrf in the application.

So you are right, login csrf is usually just a small building block, and one of its uses may be hiding things from the audit log, or make way to other csrf.

You are also right that it's a somewhat lower risk in many cases, for example in many bug bounty programmes login csrf is excluded.

Also note though that login csrf was actively exploited in the past. Internet service providers usually give routers to their customers to be set up locally. Coax, fiber optics, whatever goes into the router (or modem), and it provides ethernet for the home network. There are a few settings that users can set, for example dhcp options, name servers, port forwards. In the past, many such routers had default local ip addresses like 192.168.1.1, and default username/passwords like admin/admin. It seemed ok, because the configuration website can only be accessed from the internal network. Also many such routers were (and in fact, still are) vulnerable to login csrf. However, an attacker can set up an external website that when visited, posts admin/admin to 192.168.1.1/login, and then in another post changes the nameservers for example, thus facilitating man in the middle attacks. An external attacker cannot do this, because he has no access to the configuration ui, but with csrf he can, with a visitor from the internal network. In this case too, login csrf is very useful, but again, this is kind of an edge case, but another one.